# React native image, dynamic require

Tags: react-native

I am trying to include dynamic images in my app.

```
     const newVideo = {
            ...
            iconPath: `require('../assets/images/${icon}.png')`
        };
```

Then:

```
 <Image
          style={styles.iconStyle}
          resizeMode="contain"
          source={iconPath}
        />
```

However, I don't see my image or an error, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You could store your images in corresponding folders for ios and android, and then calling them like that :

```
<Image
  source={{ uri: 'myimage' }}
/>
```

For ios, if you use Xcode, drop your images in the Images.xcassets folder.
Check this link to see where it is : https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/FolderStructure.html

For android, you have to put them in :

- android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/   (x1 images)
- android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/   (x2 images)
- android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/  (x3 images)

Remember, no capital letter, no special character except _ for android files. You should name them the same way for IOS to avoid exceptions.

Once your images are in this folders, just build again and your images will be accessible with `{uri : "myimage"}` as source property.

I made a script to do this job for me:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');
const fs = require('fs');

const fileImport = (file, dir = '') => {
  const filePath = dir + file;
  const imgSrc = file.replace('.png', '').replace('.jpg', '');
  const extension = file.indexOf('.png') > -1 ? 'png' : 'jpg';

  const iosPath = './ios/myproject/Images.xcassets/';
  const imgFolderExtension = '.imageset';

  const androidPathx1 = './android/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/';
  const androidPathx2 = './android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/';
  const androidPathx3 = './android/app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/';

  const jsonContentIos = `{
        "images" : [
          {
            "idiom" : "universal",
            "filename" : "${imgSrc}.${extension}",
            "scale" : "1x"
          },
          {
            "idiom" : "universal",
            "filename" : "${imgSrc}@2x.${extension}",
            "scale" : "2x"
          },
          {
            "idiom" : "universal",
            "filename" : "${imgSrc}@3x.${extension}",
            "scale" : "3x"
          }
        ],
        "info" : {
          "version" : 1,
          "author" : "xcode"
        }
      }`;

  const createImageIos = x => {
    sharp(filePath)
      .metadata()
      .then(info => {
        sharp(filePath)
          .resize(parseInt(info.width / (x === 1 ? 3 : x === 2 ? 1.5 : 1), 10))
          .toFile(
            iosPath +
              imgSrc +
              imgFolderExtension +
              '/' +
              imgSrc +
              (x === 1 ? '' : x === 2 ? '@2x' : '@3x') +
              '.' +
              extension,
            err => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                console.log('Success iOS @x' + x);
              }
            }
          );
      });
  };

  const createImageAndroid = x => {
    sharp(filePath)
      .metadata()
      .then(info => {
        sharp(filePath)
          .resize(parseInt(info.width / (x === 1 ? 3 : x === 2 ? 1.5 : 1), 10))
          .toFile(
            (x === 1
              ? androidPathx1
              : x === 2
                ? androidPathx2
                : androidPathx3) +
              imgSrc +
              '.png',
            err => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                console.log('Success Android @x' + x);
              }
            }
          );
      });
  };

  // Create folder of the image inside IOS Native folder
  if (!fs.existsSync(iosPath + imgSrc + imgFolderExtension)) {
    console.log('Folder created', iosPath + imgSrc + imgFolderExtension);
    fs.mkdirSync(iosPath + imgSrc + imgFolderExtension);
    // Write Contents.json
    fs.writeFile(
      iosPath + imgSrc + imgFolderExtension + '/Contents.json',
      jsonContentIos,
      'utf8',
      () => {
        console.log('Contents.json created in Ios folder');
        createImageIos(3);
        createImageIos(2);
        createImageIos(1);
        createImageAndroid(3);
        createImageAndroid(2);
        createImageAndroid(1);
      }
    );
  } else {
    console.log('Image already imported');
  }
};

const argv = process.argv[2];
if (!argv) {
  console.log('Missing argument');
  process.exit();
}

if (argv.indexOf('.png') > -1 || argv.indexOf('.jpg') > -1) {
  fileImport(argv);
} else {
  const realDir = argv.indexOf('/') > -1 ? argv : argv + '/';
  fs.readdirSync(realDir).forEach(file => {
    console.log('file', file);
    if (file.indexOf('.png') > -1 || file.indexOf('.jpg') > -1) {
      fileImport(file, realDir);
    }
  });
}
```

It takes one parameter, a folder or an image. You need to install sharp to make it work. ( `npm i sharp` )
It will transform your 3x images to 2x and 1x and will copy them in corresponding folders. Don't forget to replace the project name for IOS folder.

Comment: you don't need require with my method but only a string corresponding to the image name, so iconPath would equal icon and image should show up yes. but your edited question differs from the original question, so now my answer seems inappropriate to your needs